# Average of a vector-valued function over an interior edge - Finite elements

Tags: fluid-dynamics, finite-element-method

I'm reading a paper about a method with finite elements on Stoke's equation, and I found something I hadn't seen before.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNRyQ.png)

What does $\epsilon$(**w**) mean?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, is the scalar average of **w**

- Bibliography

https://math.okstate.edu/people/yqwang/publications/2011-sisc-aposterioriHdiv.pdf